# Difference in blocking between sys.log() and console.log() and console.error()?

Tags: node.js

1. Is any one of sys.log(), console.log(), console.error() blocking? (var sys = require("sys");)
2. How is sys.log() different from console.log();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.error` is blocking (it calls sync write in [writeError](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_stdio.cc#L167)).

`console.log` is non-blocking = `process.stdout.write(util.format.apply(this, arguments) + '\n');`

`sys.log` == `util.log` == `puts(timestamp() + ' - ' + msg.toString());` (non-blocking)

Answer (score 1):

From Firebug Wiki:

> console.log writes a message to the console. You may pass as many
>   arguments as you'd like, and they will be joined together in a
>   space-delimited line.
>
> console.error writes a message to the console with the visual "error"
>   icon and color coding and a hyperlink to the line where it was called.

AFAIK they are not blocking.

sys.log is not native in the browsers I use. Maybe you can provide more info on that.

UPDATE: just noticed your node.js tag...
Anyhow, I still don't think any of them is blocking.

Comment: The question was in teh context of node.js but thanks anyway!